# How to recreate a bar chart of event times in Excel

Tags: excel

Trying to recreate this first graph in excel using the data below it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by making the times regular integers, then calculating the start to end difference for each date, widening the data to split the differences among three categories. I then highlighted only the dates and start times, pressed control, and highlighted the 3 columns with the differences.

[image]

I selected stacked bar chart, which looked like this by default.

[image]

Lastly, I selected the (blue) start time bars and chose no fill as the color. After deleting this series from the legend, the result adequately matched the requirements.

[image]